# How to set a timeout on a Primefaces ajax request?

Tags: ajax, primefaces

I ame facing issues with Primefaces Ajax requests where the Server does not respond for a longer time (say 30 seconds). In that case, it seems that the Ajax request is running into a timeout (either the browser or the Network stack times out). Essentially, what happens then is that the Ajax Animation (that turning circle) runs indefinitely (even if the Response arrives after that time, it does not get considered).

Since users reported to face that Kind of issue espacially during mobile usage, I started to investigate further. To reproduce, I use fiddler and set the oSession["response-trickle-delay"] = "30000";

I tried to search on Google and Stackoverflow but most of the other questions seem to be related to session timeout. There, the proposed solution is to implement an exception handler on the Server. In my case though, there is no session timeout.

I assume that in all the cases where it Comes to a request timeout, poor Network is the cause. Therefore, I rather would want to set something like a timeout on the cient side to tell the application to stop waiting for the Response to return.

I know that in jquery something like this can be done with the following code. Is there an equivalent Approach for Primefaces?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/your_ajax_method/",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 3000, 
    success: function(response) { alert(response); },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {...    }
});​
```

Thanks!

Comment: Seen this: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=39224? Might be worth a try (and a 'google tip' (I needed it too to find this link) is that you can add -session to have results **not** contain the word)

Comment: Interesting! Are you suggesting that Primefaces is making use of jquery for it's Ajax calls under the Hood? Could it be as simple as calling $.ajaxSetup({
  timeout: 15000
}); ??

Comment: Yes, it does. It might be that simple. But keep in mind it is global then, unless maybe you do it in the onstart and oncomplete of a specific component

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set timeout on jsf/primefaces ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52402446/how-to-set-timeout-on-jsf-primefaces-ajax-request)

Comment: How to set timeout for specific request look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52402446/how-to-set-timeout-on-jsf-primefaces-ajax-request