# How to set timeout on jsf/primefaces ajax request?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am using **JSF2/Primefaces** and I was wondering how to implement a timeout callback either with jsf or primefaces ?

I want to make the timeout for the ajax request 30 seconds and if the request timed out do something as a callback .

Comment: The source of both is open. This part is most likely in some javascript. You could investigate how to set a timeout by downloading the source (or checking in github)

Comment: So in the mean time between me commenting and you providing the bounty you did not try anything? Maybe your call should be made async...

Comment: Kukeltje, i didn't actually i thought maybe someone already knows a way to accomplish this in jsf or primefaces or omnifaces maybe

Comment: Hmmm... that sort of does not feel good. Please read http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ (I did not downvote) and also please read http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive... I noticed you were online multiple times the last days and Effectively this question was a RTFM ;-)... Please remember all these things for next questions.

Comment: Kukeltje, well it's my bad that i didn't made very good search before asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I put my foot where my mouth is and investigated the source and [found a hint](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/271a52100de06d8c8a339025e9a0b4c5500e31a0/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/core/core.ajax.js#L527). Not to clear but a start so I did some quick [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=primefaces%20set%20ajax%20timeout) and one of the first hits was a [PrimeFaces forum topic](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=53079) about setting the timeout

As a result of this (weird that I did not do that upfront), I opended the [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_2.pdf) and searched for `timeout`. Lots of hits and it in the end turned out you could do

```
<p:ajax timeout="30000" ... />
<p:commandButton timeout="30000" ... />
```

etc... So it is already built in

For acting on the 'error' there is the onerror eventhandler which takes the name of a javascript function for basic ajax handling

```
<p:ajax timeout="30000" onerror="doMyErrorThing" ... />
<p:commandButton timeout="30000" onerror="doMyErrorThing"... />

function doMyErrorThing(...) {
    // do your thing
}
```

To call a server-side method in that case call a `p:remoteCommand` and all should be as you want it

Comment: Kukeltje, thanks a lot for your effort and your advises